# product of binomial coefficients taken some or all at atime

Tags: binomial-coefficients

If $\binom{n}{0} , \binom{n}{1} , \binom{n}{2} , \binom{n}{2} .... \binom{n}{n}$ denote the binomial coefficients in the expansion of ${(1+1)}^n$ then what is the difference between

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n} \sum_{s=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r}\binom{n}{s}$$

and

$$\sum \sum \binom{n}{r}\binom{n}{s}$$

$r$ is greater than or equal to $0$ but it is less than $s$ and $s$ is less than or equal to $n$

How can we understand the differences in the meaning of the questions ?

Comment: The first one sums to $2^{2n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The products that are in the double summations can be featured in the following double array (for $n=4$):

$$\begin{array}{|l||l|l|l|l|}
\hline
&\color{red}{\binom{4}{0}}&\color{red}{\binom{4}{1}}&\color{red}{\binom{4}{2}}&\color{red}{\binom{4}{3}}&\color{red}{\binom{4}{4}}\\ 
\hline
\color{red}{\binom{4}{0}}&&*&*&*&*\\
\hline
\color{red}{\binom{4}{1}}&&&*&*&*\\
\hline
\color{red}{\binom{4}{2}}&&&&*&*\\
\hline
\color{red}{\binom{4}{3}}&&&&&*\\
\hline
\color{red}{\binom{4}{4}}&&&&&\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

The first sum uses all the boxes. The second sum, assumed to be

$$\sum \sum \binom{n}{r}\binom{n}{s} \  \text{for} \ 0 \leq r < s\leq n$$

uses only the starred boxes.

Comment: You are right. I correct it.

Comment: @JeanMarie I’m sorry I guess in the question the limits that you used first were right. Could you please correct accordingly ?

Comment: I  did it , with the corresponding assumption that the last  "$<$" is "$\leq$".

Comment: and r is also greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: This doesn't change the starred boxes.

Comment: Alright thank you very much !!

Comment: can this also be called as the sum of the binomial coefficients taken two at a time ?

Comment: Yes for the second sum. Note that the first sum is the expansion of $(\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n})^2$

Answer (score 1):

The following representations of the double sums might be useful.

> We have
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{s=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\binom{n}{s}&=\sum_{\color{blue}{0\leq r,s\leq n}}\binom{n}{r}\binom{n}{s}
> =\sum_{s=0}^n\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\binom{n}{s}\\
> \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sum_{s=r+1}^n\binom{n}{r}\binom{n}{s}&=\sum_{\color{blue}{0\leq r<s\leq n}}\binom{n}{r}\binom{n}{s}
> =\sum_{s=1}^n\sum_{r=0}^{s-1}\binom{n}{r}\binom{n}{s}\
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{s=0}^n{n\choose r}{n\choose s}=2\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sum_{s=r+1}^n{n\choose r}{n\choose s}+\sum_{t=0}^n{n\choose t}^2$$

Comment: I have assumed that $0\leq r\lt s\leq n$ just to give the idea. Otherwise change limits accordingly.